# How to get value from dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, key, nsdictionary

everyone!

Please help me to get the total value from given dictionary

```
 {
    "@averageBaseRate" = "296.7";
    "@averageRate" = "296.7";
    "@commissionableUsdTotal" = "1186.8";
    "@currencyCode" = USD;
    "@maxNightlyRate" = "296.7";
    "@nightlyRateTotal" = "1186.8";
    "@total" = "1186.8";
    NightlyRatesPerRoom =     {
        "@size" = 1;
        NightlyRate =         {
....
```

How can I get the value from total key. Neither I can apply valueForKey nor I can apply objectForKey.

Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will reward you in your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks strange that you have "@total" instead of "total" - looks like @ is a  part of NSString.
Probably you created a NSString @"@total" which sounds like a bug.
You should be able to access it with:

```
[dict objectForKey:@"@total"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
float total = [[yourDict objectForKey:@"@total"] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Buddy always use like this ........

with this line you get all value of ABC Key In your Array

```
                 [array addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"ABC"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowerdays, you could even use
`yourDict[@"yourkey"]`
 to get the value you stored for yourkey.